# java.lang.IllegalCastException for GWT

Tags: java, exception, gwt, casting

I'm getting an IllegalCastException on the following (see bold line):

```
public void renderXML(final String xml) {
    final Document xmlDoc = XMLParser.parse(xml);
    final com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
    XMLParser.removeWhitespace(xmlDoc);

    final NodeList collection = root.getElementsByTagName("collection");
      for (int i = 0; i < collection.getLength(); i++) {
        **final Element coll= (Element)collection.item(i);**
        RootPanel.get("slot2").add(new Label("coll: "));
      }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is so? I've looked at examples, and it seems that this is supposed to be how to do it. I am using the following related imports:

```
 import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
 import com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList;
 import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;
```

One thing to make note of here...Element is imported as "import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;", I cannot import "import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;" as it will give me the error:

"The import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element collides with another import statement"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList.item` returns a `com.google.gwt.xml.client.Node`, not `com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element`. Such a `Node` might be an `Element`, but there is no guarantee. You must check the type of the `item` that is returned before casting it.

Also, you must use the appropriate `Element`; you can't substitute one for the other. You must either avoid importing the other `Element`, or fully specify the `Element` you need here.

For instance, assuming in your code you only care about `Element`, and you don't eliminate the other import, then you can change your loop to be as such:

```
final NodeList collection = root.getElementsByTagName("collection");
for (int i = 0; i < collection.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = collection.item(i);
    if (!(node instanceof com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element)) {
        continue;
    }

    com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element coll =
    (com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element)node;
    RootPanel.get("slot2").add(new Label("coll: "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to import directly into the source code instead of declaring at the import lines?

```
public void renderXML(final String xml) {
        // just directly import it as local variable. 
        final Document xmlDoc = com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser.XMLParser.parse(xml);
        final com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
        XMLParser.removeWhitespace(xmlDoc);

        final NodeList collection = root.getElementsByTagName("collection");
          for (int i = 0; i < collection.getLength(); i++) {
            **final Element coll= (Element)collection.item(i);**
            RootPanel.get("slot2").add(new Label("coll: "));
          }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Tiger